# ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I created a table 'user_info' in DynamoDB with one primary hash key 'user_id'(String), no range key. Then I created 2 AWS lambda functions to insert and query the items. I can insert items into the table, but when I query the table, it returns:

> ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the
>   schema.

**My query function :**

```
var params = {
   Key: {
       user_id:{
           S: "usr1@s.com"
       }
   },
    TableName: 'user_info',
    ProjectionExpression: 'password'
};

dynamodb.getItem(params,
 function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("get item err." + err);
        context.done('error','getting item from dynamodb failed: '+err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('great success: '+JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
        context.succeed('created user ' + event.user_id + ' successfully.');
    }
});
```

I keep getting this exception:

```
ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Since

1) I have only one hash primary key.

2)user_id is defined as String. I really don't know why there is a mismatch error.

Answer (score 56):

To clarify further on why this is happening, you were originally using the [DynamoDB Document Client](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk), which eliminates to need to explicitly label your attributes as "String" (S) or "Number" (N) etc. Therefore, your original code would have worked with

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamodb = new doc.DynamoDB();

var params = {
Key: {
   user_id: "usr1@s.com"
},
TableName: 'user_info',
ProjectionExpression: 'password'
};
```

Note the "S" wrapping the value of "user_id" is removed from the above code. Later on, you switched back to the low-level javascript sdk by using 'aws-sdk', so your code with "S" label ended up working.

Comment: Thank you so much! I always hated DynamoDb's types and wasn't aware of the Document Client (which is now part of the official SDK). Your answer saved me much grief!

Comment: Very useful, I was using just new AWS.DynamoDB and I had to include the attribute type, when I switched over to use new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient() I kept getting "ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema" without it telling me what was wrong. Leaving out the attribute type fixed the error!

Comment: I ran into the same problem when I tried to make my code as close as possible to AWS code samples, official documentation. When I removed the "S" and "N" and reverted back to the old style, the error disappeared! I went even as far as creating an index and trying all sorts of other things because the error message didn't help in narrowing down on the source! I think it is high time AWS updates the documentation: as far as documentation is considered, consistency isn't the word that I would use for AWS. Thanks a lot Daniela.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. AWS typing is really messy. I used Document Client but tried to initialize DB request using types attributes with "S", "N" notations (BatchWriteItemCommandOutput type). But had to use BatchWriteCommandInput type.

Answer (score 20):

At last, I found out the answer. It's not about the format of params, but with the code before it, which I did not post in my question. When I replace

```
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamodb = new doc.DynamoDB();
```

with

```
var doc = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new doc.DynamoDB();
```

the exception disappears.

Comment: Thanks .This helps me..:)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a million, some things seem so obvious once you read them here.

Answer (score 7):

(Different Scenario than OP)

This same error was happening to me when I was trying to query by just a **HASH** key when my table had both a **HASH** and **SORT** Key. I removed the unused **SORT** key as it wasn't needed for me and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by a simple coding error where the querying key's data type is different from the one defined in the schema.

For example, the key is defined as `String` in the schema (see `AttributeDefinitions`):

```
 resources:
 Resources:
   RemarksDynamoDbTable:
     Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
     DeletionPolicy: Retain
     Properties:
       TableName: "chat-admin-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}"
       ProvisionedThroughput:
         ReadCapacityUnits: 1
         WriteCapacityUnits: 1
       AttributeDefinitions:
         - AttributeName: id
           AttributeType: S         
       KeySchema:
         - AttributeName: id
           KeyType: HASH
```

But it's specified as `Number` (N) when querying:

```
result, err := svc.GetItem(&dynamodb.GetItemInput{
TableName: aws.String(table),
Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
    "id": {
        N: aws.String(key),
    },
},})
```