# DynamoDB = why am I getting "The provided key element does not match the schema" error when I am passing valid values?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to delete records from dynamo based on partition and sort key. My logic pulls the data which are valid (i.e. I get the values from logic, go to dynamo and I can perform the query successfully).

Now when I am trying to delete it by `.batchItem` then I am getting `The provided key element does not match the schema`.

I have seen some stackOverflow questions similar to this where either you are not passing correct Keys OR partition/sort key is missing in `Key` attribute which is not the case here.

What am I missing here?

**Dynamo Table:**

[image]

**Logic to delete record:**

```
const requestItems = {
            [tableName]: patch.map(item => {
                numItemsDeleted++;
                const records = {
                    DeleteRequest: {
                        Key: {
                            "tenantId": tenantId,
                            [hashKey]: item[hashKey]
                        }
                    }
                };
                // console.log("records", records);
                return records;
            })
        };

        if (requestItems[tableName].length > 0) {
            // Getting error in below step.
            await DynamoDb.batchWrite({ RequestItems: requestItems }).promise();
            console.log(`finished deleting ${numItemsDeleted} items this batch`);
        }
```

**Output:**

```
{
    DeleteRequest:
    {
        Key:
        {
            tenantId: 'SOME-GUID',
            'channelOrderCreated#id#status': 'aaa#bbb#ccc'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can write `"tenantId": tenantId` as simply `tenantId`.

Comment: I guess the problem is with the data types. So just try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31890650/10758654) if you're doing the same.

Comment: @jarmod does that really matter? I think we can write it both ways right?

Comment: @SaiSreenivas Correct, it's not causing a problem. But it's more idiomatic in modern JavaScript, and hence is preferred. Regarding the problem, I would be tempted to change this code temporarily to loop over each item and delete them one by one, first printing out the JSON of the exact key value sent to the API, and catch and print all exceptions.

Comment: Thanks and yeah if nothing works doing what you've said would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your feed back. This change worked for me. I still have some questions which I am going to research now but let me explain what happened (my best guess):

1. This table has partition key = `tenantId` and sort key = `id#status`.
2. `channelOrderCreated#id#status` is LSI. I needed that because I do not want query entire table. This LSI would allow me pull data based on time frame.
3. Now, for some reason, Dynamo did not like when I use the same index in `Key` element. Is this because sortKey is `id#status`? I honestly don't know.
4. So what I did was, pull the data based on `channelOrderCreated#id#status` and then delete the data based on `id#status` which worked.

**Pull the data:**

```
const res = await DynamoDb.query({
    TableName: tableName,
    IndexName: 'index_channelOrderCreated_id_status',
    ExclusiveStartKey: lastEvaluatedKey,
    KeyConditionExpression:
        '#tenantId = :tenantId And begins_with(#orderCreatedDate, :orderCreatedDate)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":tenantId": tenantId,
        ":orderCreatedDate": beginsWith,
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#tenantId": "tenantId",
        "#orderCreatedDate": "channelOrderCreated#id#status"
    }
}).promise();
```

**Delete the data:**

```
   const requestItems = {
        [tableName]: patch.map(item => {
            // console.log("item -> ", item);
            numItemsDeleted++;
            const records = {
                DeleteRequest: {
                    Key: {
                        "tenantId": tenantId,
                        ["id#status"]: item["id#status"]
                    }
                }
            };
            // console.log("records", records);
            return records;
        })
    };
```